# Woocommerce: how can I show only one or more categories to vendors?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I need to set only one or few categories for each vendor (specific user).
Is it possible? Is there any plugin for this?

Comment: please, read **[asking](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)**
and take a look at  **[how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**

Answer (score 0):

Generally it's not good form to use Stack Overflow to find stuff. It's better to look yourself and show what you've done and why it's not working.

That said, I would recommend you get a plugin that lets you create additional user roles. Then you would need to use [Catalog Visibility Options](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/catalog-visibility-options/) to change category visibility on a per-role basis (http://docs.woothemes.com/document/catalog-visibility-options/#section-4).